# Find subdocument in specific collection

Tags: mongoose

I want to find subdocument (keywords) in specific collection (name : countries).
*Mongoose 5.10.8*

```json
{
    "name" : "jobs",
    "keywords" : [...],
    ...
},
{
    "name" : "countries",
    "keywords" : [ 
        {
            "active" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f626eb337fd4d75ab694108"),
            "name" : "japan"
        }, 
        {
            "active" : true,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5f626eb337fd4d75ab694109"),
            "name" : " france"
        }
    ],
}
```

I need to retrive the name of country eg: France, Belgium
I tried that, but no result :

```js
async function getCountryName(id_country){
    try{
        const result = await Dictionary
            .find({name: 'countries'})
            .where('keywords.id').equals(id_country)
            .select('name')
            .exec()
        console.log(result);
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: you want to get a list of all names of the country ?

Comment: No, I want pick just one country.
For example, I have this _id `5f626eb337fd4d75ab694108` and the request return me `Japan`. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$keywords"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "keywords._id": ObjectId("5f626eb337fd4d75ab694108")
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      name: "$keywords.name"
    }
  }
])
```

check result [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vlSyKwrKMsb)

Comment: Thank @Tahero, I'll try your solution because I use Mongoose.

Comment: Juste one thing, in my case I want to browse only the collection "countries".
```const result = await Dictionary.aggregate([
 {$unwind: '$keywords'},
 {$match: {$and: [{name: 'countries'},  {'keywords._id':ObjectId(id_country)}]}},
 {$project: {name: "$keywords.name"}}
]);```